# how to use function to require php file not changing global vars environment?

Tags: php

how to use function to require php file not changing global vars environment?
if using function ,and in function codes "require(xxx.php)",then all the vars in xxx.php are not global vars again. for the example bellow , I want to get the result is "linjuming", but the oop.php is required in the require_part() function ,so echo $name is not 'linjuming' any more. 
pls dont use global $name in require_part function . for this function is a common function to require any php file. other php files have their own global vars.
my codes here:

```
<?php
$name='linjuming';
class my_template{
    function require_part($part_name){
        if(file_exists($part_name.'php')){
            require($part_name.'php');
        }
    }
}

$tmp=new my_template();
$tmp->require_part('oop');

/*
    oop.php codes：
    <?php echo $name; ?>

    I want to run component php file and do not change the global environment;
    how to do that?

 */
?>
```

Comment: what global var are you changing here exactly ?

Comment: i'm not sure what you're asking. Please explain in examples what your expected output.

Comment: Can you provide context for your use case? It looks like you try to solve nonexistent problem.

Comment: First of all, your require method is not including anything, it will look for a file call `oopphp`, it's missing a dot. Second I believe `global` is not what you think it does. Global variables can always be overwritten, no matter the scope. It only makes it possible to extend the scope of a variable name somewhere where it has not been defined. Your PHP files included in the method is bound to the scope of `my_template::require`, not the main scope where `$name` is defined.

Comment: If you don't want globals to change, don't use global scope for your code. Simple. Then you don't care what's happening or doesn't happen in it :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your commented out line, it seems you want to be able to use `$name` as a global variable.

```
<?php 
    global $name;
    echo $name;
?>
```

Read more about variable scope [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Alternatively, you can use:

```
echo $this->name;
```

Comment: works, but is there some other methods? thank you

Comment: You can use `$this->name;`